# What is the meaning of "lowest stable non-descript"?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, charles-dickens

In Chapter 2 of Charles Dickens' *A Tale of Two Cities* I read the following:

> As to the latter, when every posting-house and ale-house could produce somebody in “the Captain’s” pay, ranging from the landlord to the lowest stable non-descript, it was the likeliest thing upon the cards.

What is the contextual meaning of "lowest stable non-descript"? Is "stable" an adjective? Or what is its grammatical role? Whom or what does the term "lowest stable non-descript" refer to? Should not the term be "lowest non-descript" or "lowest non-descript of the stable", instead of "lowest stable non-descript"? What is the term "stable" doing here?

Comment: Nondescript: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nondescript

Comment: stable: a group of people who perform a similar activity and who are trained by the same person or employed by the same organization. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stable

Comment: @user66974 - But this literally refers to a worker in the inn stable.

Comment: I think ***nondescript*** there is really just an emphatic "lower than the lowest" twist on somewhat cliched [*the lowest **stable-boy.***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+lowest+stable-boy%22)